# data stored in array but for specific elements it is showing undefined in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/info/admincontact').then(res => {
      this.setState({
        blogid: res.data
      });
      console.log(this.state.blogid)
      console.log(this.state.blogid.city);
    })
```

###CONSOLE

> Array(2)0: city: "Salem"email: "sachinvijay@gmail.com"map: "https://www.google.com/maps/place/ITPL/@12.9859537,77.7322496,13z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sitpl!3m4!1s0x3bae11e4fb1b21a5:0x6018797bb4fac8b2!8m2!3d12.9874525!4d77.7370219"phone: "9600337763"state: "Tamil Nadu"__v: 0_id: "5f45444391b5a456bc90d7f7"**proto**: Object1: city: "Salem"email: "sachinvijay@gmail.com"mapl: "https://www.google.com/maps/place/ITPL/@12.9859537,77.7322496,13z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sitpl!3m4!1s0x3bae11e4fb1b21a5:0x6018797bb4fac8b2!8m2!3d12.9874525!4d77.7370219"phone: "9600337763"state: "Tamil Nadu"**v: 0_id: "5f45497b9120014680289a99"**proto**: Objectlength: 2__proto**: Array(0)
> Contact.js:49 undefined

Answer (score 0):

React setState is not a synchronous function, so you'd better write like this.

```
this.setState({blogid: res.data}, () => {
          console.log(this.state.blogid)
          console.log(this.state.blogid.city);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an array in the `blogid`, so you need to either iterate or you can use the particular index of it:

```
this.setState({blogid: res.data}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.blogid[0].city);
});
```

and yes you have to log it in the callback of the `setState` because it is ***async*** and it's value take a bit of time to update. Callback will ensure that it will only log when the `setState` operation is done/fulfilled.

or you can use `forEach`:

```
this.state.blogid.forEach(obj => console.log(obj.city));
```